# lp command can’t open samba url

Tags: linux, printing, samba

I have a Linux host with Samba installed and a Windows server with some Files.
Samba is set up correctly and works just fine.
I can show PDFs from the Windows server with

```
evince "smb://SRV/Share/.../xx.pdf"
```

but when I want to print this file with

```
lp –d lpX "smb://SRV/Share/.../xx.pdf"
```

an error occurs:

```
lp: Error – Access ?smb://SRV/Share/.../xx.pdf? not possible - File or Directory not found
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lp` is a core Linux utility and doesn't understand non-file based names such as `smb://`.

evince is a gnome application which understands urls.

You should be able to use:

```
smbget -O "smb://SRV/Share/.../xx.pdf" | lp -d lpX -
```

to print from a samba url.

smbget accepts the `-u` username and `-p` for the password (otherwise it prompts for them). You can use `-a` for anonymous access, which causes it to try without a username/password

Comment: Thanks a lot! I searched a lot on the Internet, but never would I have found this. Works like a charm!